# How to run a function in R multiple times in a for loop for changing variables?

Tags: r, for-loop

```
for (n in 1:clustNum) {
    nam <- paste("ATV", n, sep = "")
    assign(nam, z[which(nb$Best. partition == n),])
}
```

This is my current for loop to assign the variables to the data but I need to run a function on the data as well.
Basically I have variables called `ATV1`,`ATV2`, etc, how can a run a function on them all in a for loop?

Or are there any simpler ways to do it?

Comment: It's best to use a list instead of a `for` loop and `assign`. Make a vector of names and call `lapply` on it.

Comment: How does *z*, *clustNum*, and *nb* relate? Please show assignment or use random or mock data.

Comment: z is a cbind of x and y coordinates, clust num is a variable calculated using nb,